# Чи потрібне тире у слогані "З користувача — в творця"?

Tags: пунктуація

Чи потрібне тире у слогані: *"З користувача — в творця"*?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Запитання, які не демонструють **спроби автора самостійно відповісти** на нього, змушують інших користувачів повторювати роботу, що її, можливо, вже було виконано автором запитання. Це заважає надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть [edit] у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням. Ще раз, ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такий слоган **не вимагає** постановки тире.

«Генеральний регіонально анотований корпус української мови» версії 10 має [приклади без тире](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%3Cs%3E+%5Bword=%22(?i)%D1%96?%D0%B7%22%5D+%5Btag=%22noun.*v_rod.*%22%5D+%5Bword=%22%D0%B2%7C%D1%83%7C%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%96?%22%5D+%5Btag=%22noun.*v_zna.*%22%5D+%5Bword=%22%5B.?!%E2%80%A6%5D%2B%22%5D?+%3C/s%3E), зокрема: (про перетворення суб'єкта) *«із дранки в перепіранку»*, *«із яструбів у голуби»*; (про зміну стану, яку, здається, можна вважати як перетворенням суб'єкта, так і фізичним переміщенням) *«із забуття в безсмертя»*, *«з пітьми у світло»*, *«з пустелі у пущу»*; багато прикладів про фізичне переміщення.

Але тире **можна й поставити**, наприклад, згідно з [§ 121.4](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par121p4) чи [§ 121.17](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par121p17) «Українського правопису» 2015 року (с. 174 і с. 177 відповідно):

> Тире ставиться: <…>
>
> На місці пропущеного члена речення, переважно присудка. [Вважаючи, що повне речення звучить «з користувача *перетворитися* в творця» — коментар мій.] <…>
>
> Взагалі для означення спеціально підкреслюваної паузи різного змістового й стилістичного характеру. [Вважаючи, що ми хочемо спеціально підкреслювану паузу — коментар мій.] <…>

«Генеральний регіонально анотований корпус української мови» версії 10 має і [приклади з тире](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%3Cs%3E+%5Bword=%22(?i)%D1%96?%D0%B7%22%5D+%5Btag=%22noun.*v_rod.*%22%5D+%5Bword=%22%5B%E2%80%94%E2%80%93%E2%88%92%E2%80%90-%5D%2B%22%5D+%5Bword=%22%D0%B2%7C%D1%83%7C%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%96?%22%5D+%5Btag=%22noun.*v_zna.*%22%5D+%5Bword=%22%5B.?!%E2%80%A6%5D%2B%22%5D?+%3C/s%3E), зокрема: (про перетворення суб'єкта) *«із депутата — у політики»*; (про зміну стану, яку, здається, можна вважати як перетворенням суб'єкта, так і фізичним переміщенням) *«з холоду — в жар»*; кілька прикладів про фізичне переміщення.